# UIPickerview in iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, xcode3.2

How to reduce the size of UIPickerview in a subView? I am reducing the CGRectMake(120, 20, 60,25). But it appears in the normal size. What i do now?

Some One help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method below

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

This will resolve the issue.You can also refer the same from apple documentation.

[image]
Cheers

Aditya